# SwiftUI - MenuBarExtra with .window style: Layout issue with ScrollView

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-menu, menubarextra

I tried to create a menubar application for macOS but since it contains multiple Views in a Scroll, as you may imagine, i had to use `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)`.

So far so good.

The point is: the first time I open the menu the height seems to layout properly, but from the second time on, the view resizes to a certain smaller height amount.
You can try with this simple snippet:

```
MenuBarExtra("", systemImage: "info") {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(0..<100) {
                Text("Row \($0)")
            }
        }
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
```

Changing `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)` to `.menuBarExtraStyle(.menu)` fixes the problem but of course you can't build your own layout, functionalities, etc... taking advantage of the `.window` style just display.

Even setting a maximum height - `.frame(maxHeight: maxHeight)` - for the ScrollView, doesn't seem to solve this behavior.

Same result setting `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` for the VStack in the example code.

Did anyone faced this issue? Maybe there's a proper way to proceed and build this kind of layout maintaining the height stable?

Comment: Why do you think the result when you first open the menu is "proper"? The height can exceed the height of some screens, and you cannot even scroll. The height when you open it for the second time should be the correct one.

Comment: Hi Sweeper!
i supposed it was proper because of the expectations and the attempts I made:
As I wrote, if you add to the ScrollView, the modifier `.frame(maxHeight: maxHeight)`  - where maxHeight may be for example `NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size.height` it still collapses. 
You can try it yourself easily with the code I shared.
If you have any suggestions to adapt the height of the scrollview to its content, when `.menuBarExtraStyle` is `.window`, I'll be glad to try. indeed, as I said, the weird thing is that if the style is `.menu`, it works properly.
Thank you for answering 